# Custom Node module to install dependencies

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, yeoman

Currently I have a custom Yeoman generator for some applications. This generator requires some dependencies and configurations.

1 - GruntJS to be installed globally;

2 - Bower to be installed globally;

3 - Yeoman to be installed globally;

4 - Some other configurations to be in place;

**Question**: Is there any tool to manage this dependencies work flow?

Optimally, I'm hoping for a two-step process

1 - Install Node.Js

2 - npm install my-generator

The second step will be responsible for installing all the packages globally.

I saw some examples that used preinstall script in the *package.json* like below:

```
...
scripts: {
  preinstall: 'npm install bower -g; npm install grunt-cli -g'
}
...
```

This solution did not work for me and I also read in several places that this is an anti-pattern.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's antipattern because `npm` normally downgrades the superuser permission before execute preinstall scripts. But in order to install global packages you have to execute it as `sudo`. The problem is that you need to make your instalation **unsafe** by giving superpowers to npm install scripts.

You can do it by creating a `.npmrc` file in your project root directory with the following content:

```
unsafe-perm = true
```

You package.json will look like:

```
{
  "name": "foo",
  "version": "1.4.4",
  "scripts" :  { 
    "preinstall" : "npm install -g bower; npm install -g grunt-cli"
  }
}
```

Then you can run

```
sudo npm install
```

Comment: That is ok, but is this a really bad idea? I tried adding as a config parameter and it didn't work. It only works when you have it inside .npmrc. This is strange...

Comment: There's a simpla way: `npm install -g yourapp bower grunt-cli`